# Can I get graph access token from exchange user identity token in outlook add-in?

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

According to documentation at [Exchange user Identity token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authentication#exchange-user-identity-token), I can use user identity token `as a fallback authentication (and authorization to Microsoft Graph) when the add-in is running on a version of Office that doesn't support SSO.`

But I did not get any way to use this id token in context of firing graph APIs. Am I missing something here?

I am working on a outlook addin, which doesn't support SSO in browsers where third-party cookie access is blocked. Is there any way for fetching graph access token from exchange id token or callback tokens?

I want to avoid using popup for authentication as this is creating unnecessary friction in user flow in Safari and Chrome incognito.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation that you linked is misleading. (I will open an issue with the documentation team) The Exchange User Identity Token, is meant so that you can recognize the user against your own backend, not against Graph. As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authenticate-a-user-with-an-identity-token). So you would have to make the graph call from your own backend, in order to make use of the Exchange User Identity Token. (which may not be what you want)

Take a look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph-without-sso

And

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api

To see if these may help your situation.

As an additional follow-up, is there a specific platform you are trying this out on? (Mac, Win32, OWA), or presumably you need this to work on all platforms.

Comment: I am making graph calls from my backend only but with the user access token. Yes, I want this to work on all platforms. This dialog flow is creating unnecessary friction in the user flow.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to avoid a dialog if SSO is not available. Once you get a graph token, you could store it in your backend and then refresh it. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) Then you could use the Exchange User Identity Token for the user, so they don't have to sign into YOUR service again.